# Not understanding how Python Class works

Tags: python, django

I am in need of some help understanding how Python and Django work based on some code I'm looking at.

Say my `urls.py` file has the following

```
router.register(r'testing', SomeClass)
```

and then in my views.py file, it is set up like this:

```
class SomeClass():
    database = DatabaseValues.objects.all()

    def first_def(self):
        # do some filtering and such on db results

        return database

    def second_def(self):
        a = 20
        b = 40
        return b - a

     def third_def(self):
        z = 200
        y = 400
        return y - z
```

When the `SomeClass` is called in UI by hitting the `http://localhost/testing` url, what is returned??

Comment: if you are httting some class as view from url then it checks for dispatch method and then it get context data method and then the logic and permission method

Comment: But this does *not* work at all. The only thing you can use with a router is a ViewSet; there are no general lessons about classes to be had here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making some changes to urls.py I think this method below is easier to understand.

when you run `python3 manage.py runserver`
you can open 127.0.0.1/example.

the reason you are not understanding is because Django has a lot of boilerplate code. I would recommend reading more into how views work.
every class in views.py should inherit a django class in this example I use `TemplateView`. your app name is the folder that is created when a new django "app" is added to the project.

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import exampleView

app_name = "example"

urlpatterns = [
    path('/example', exampleView.as_view(), name='example'),
]
```

in views.py you cannot create arbitrary function names. when a website loads 
www.baseurl/example you are making a get request. therefore you must have a `get` method inside of your class.

`template_name` refers to an html page that will be rendered...
this template name must point at an html file which is located inside `project_root/templates/html_file.html`

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView

class exampleView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'test.html'

def get(self, request):
    print("hello")
    return render(request, self.template_name, {})
```

if you wish to have arbitrary functions inside your class cool. Add them below the get function and call them when a user makes a get request.